# Get private key from Heroku

Tags: heroku, private-key

I was trying to update my certificate but I'm having issues. I issued

```
heroku certs:add server.crt server.key
```

but this command is giving me the error

> No key found that signs the certificate.

I've tried to add the key from my previous certificate, but I got the same error. I unfortunately lost my private key while trying to get a certificate with GoDaddy.

Comment: If you lost your private key there's nothing we can do to help. You need to generate a new certificate with a new private key and use that instead of the certificate you have now. (Note that Heroku includes free SSL for all paid dynos via Let's Encrypt. This is a nice easy way of getting SSL on Heroku if it's an option for you.)

Comment: Check this link https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/keys